# Entity Framework creating database with longer column names than expected

Tags: database-design, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, code-first

I have created a model

```
public class Moo
{
    public Int32 MooId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public City CityIdFrom { get; set; }
    public Int32 Weight { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class City
{
    public Int32 CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I wrote

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
             new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DbConnection>());
        ...
```

in Global.asax.cs

In short - I followed the tutorial in [here](http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro).

However, I get a database table Moo created with columns as follows:

```
   [MooId]
  ,[Description]
  ,[Weight]
  ,[CityIdFrom_CityId]
```

but, as it was in the tutorial, I expected this look as:

```
   [MooId]
  ,[Description]
  ,[Weight]
  ,[CityIdFrom]
```

**What is the reason the generator is adding unnecessary _CityId**? (same goes for all the tables' columns with relations) I am pretty sure there has to be a setting, but I find it hard to word my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not explicitly declaring the FK column in your `Moo` model.

The `CityIdFrom` property is a navigation property of type `City`, not a FK column of type `Int32`.

So, the column you're seeing in the database is created for you by EF automatically.

If you want to name this column, you have to add it to your model:

```
public class Moo
{
  public Int32 MooId { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public Int32 CityFromId { get; set; }
  public City CityFrom { get; set; }

  public Int32 Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Note: the column names are by convention so EF can figure out what goes with what.

So `CityFromId` is the database FK column for the `CityFrom` navigation property because it has the same name with `Id` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a foreign key to `City.CityId`, hence the extra `_CityId`. You'll need to add the attribute `[Column("CityIdFrom")]` in order to tell the framework that you want it to use something other than its own default.

Comment: I've added `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column("Aaa")] public City CityIdFrom{ get; set; }` but it is not changing anything :( I am probably just blind. I also delete the table before executing so I am sure it recreates the table.